# Mule OAuth2 - could not resolve 'module-security-oauth2-provider'

Tags: oauth, mule

I try to run the 'simple' example from [mulesoft](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Creating+an+OAuth+2.0a+Web+Service+Provider) but always end in the following BUILD FAILURE

```html
Failed to execute goal on project test: Could not resolve dependencies for project XXX: Failed to collect dependencies at com.mulesoft.security:mule-module-security-oauth2-provider:jar:1.3.2: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.mulesoft.security:mule-module-security-oauth2-provider:jar:1.3.2: Failure to find com.mulesoft.security:mule-module-security:pom:1.3.2 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of Central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

My flow is

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
 xmlns:oauth2-provider="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth2-provider"
 xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
 xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.6.1"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
 xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/current/mule-spring-security.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth2-provider http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth2-provider/current/mule-oauth2-provider.xsd">

 <spring:beans>
  <ss:authentication-manager id="resourceOwnerAuthenticationManager">
   <ss:authentication-provider>
    <ss:user-service id="resourceOwnerUserService">
     <ss:user name="john" password="doe" authorities="RESOURCE_OWNER" />
    </ss:user-service>
   </ss:authentication-provider>
  </ss:authentication-manager>
 </spring:beans>

 <mule-ss:security-manager>
  <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider
   name="resourceOwnerSecurityProvider" delegate-ref="resourceOwnerAuthenticationManager" />
 </mule-ss:security-manager>

 <oauth2-provider:config name="oauth2ProviderCode"
  providerName="SampleAPI" port="8081" authorizationEndpointPath="sampleapi/api/authorize"
  accessTokenEndpointPath="sampleapi/api/token"
  resourceOwnerSecurityProvider-ref="resourceOwnerSecurityProvider"
  scopes="READ_RESOURCE POST_RESOURCE" doc:name="OAuth provider module">
  <oauth2-provider:clients>
   <oauth2-provider:client clientId="myclientid"
    secret="myclientsecret" type="CONFIDENTIAL" clientName="Mule Bookstore"
    description="Mule-powered On-line Bookstore">
    <oauth2-provider:redirect-uris>
     <oauth2-provider:redirect-uri>http://localhost*</oauth2-provider:redirect-uri>
    </oauth2-provider:redirect-uris>
    <oauth2-provider:authorized-grant-types>
     <oauth2-provider:authorized-grant-type>AUTHORIZATION_CODE</oauth2-provider:authorized-grant-type>
    </oauth2-provider:authorized-grant-types>
    <oauth2-provider:scopes>
     <oauth2-provider:scope>READ_RESOURCE</oauth2-provider:scope>
     <oauth2-provider:scope>POST_RESOURCE</oauth2-provider:scope>
    </oauth2-provider:scopes>
   </oauth2-provider:client>
  </oauth2-provider:clients>
 </oauth2-provider:config>
 <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
  host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />
 <flow name="protected-authcode">
  <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
   path="/resources" doc:name="HTTP" />
  <oauth2-provider:validate config-ref="oauth2ProviderCode"
   doc:name="Validate Token" scopes="READ_RESOURCE" />
  <set-payload
   value="#[ ['name' : 'payroll', 'uri' : 'http://localhost:8081/resources/payroll'] ]"
   doc:name="Set Payload" />
  <json:object-to-json-transformer
   doc:name="Object to JSON" />
 </flow>


 <!-- THIS FLOW IS JUST AN AID TO HELP MANUAL TESTING OF THE OAUTH2 DANCE -->
 <flow name="redirectFlow">
  <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
   path="/redirect" doc:name="HTTP" />
  <set-property value="302" propertyName="http.status"
   doc:name="Property" />
  <set-property propertyName="Location"
   value="http://localhost:8081/sampleapi/api/token?grant_type=authorization_code&amp;&amp;client_id=myclientid&amp;client_secret=myclientsecret&amp;code=#[message.inboundProperties.code]
     &amp;redirect_uri=http://localhost:8081/redirect"
   doc:name="Property" />
 </flow>
</mule>
```

In my POM-file I have the following repos:

```html
...  
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.mulesoft.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>mule-module-security-oauth2-provider</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.2</version>
  </dependency>
...

<repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>Central</id>
   <name>Central</name>
   <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
   <layout>default</layout>
  </repository>
  <repository>
   <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
   <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
   <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
   <layout>default</layout>
  </repository>
  <repository>
   <id>mulesoft-snapshots</id>
   <name>MuleSoft Snapshots Repository</name>
   <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/</url>
   <layout>default</layout>
  </repository>
  <repository>
   <id>mulesoft-releases2</id>
   <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository2</name>
   <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
   <layout>default</layout>
  </repository>
 </repositories>
```

This security module belongs to Anypoint Enterprise Security and I think to remember that Mule has a secured repository for enterprise-things. Could it be that I have to contact Mule for the access?
But on the other hand there is no information about that on their site and in the given example. Do somebody has an idea what can I try to fix that and to run successfully this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a EE repo that requires a username/password combo which will be supplied by Mulesoft. You can contact them via the support portal if you are a Customer.

```
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-ee-release</id>
            <name>Mulesoft EE</name>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/</url>
        </repository>
```

Then set the username/password in your Maven `settings.xml`.